# Finding the orthogonal compliment of sets of matrices.

Tags: matrices

For $M_{22}$ we define the inner product as:

$$\langle U, V\rangle = tr (U^TV)$$

I need to describe the orthogonal compliment of the subspace of all diagonal matrices.

If I let $U =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 \\
0 & c  \\
 \end{array} \right)$ 
and $V = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
d & e \\
f & g  \\
 \end{array} \right)$

then $tr (U^TV) = ad + cg$

We want  $ad + cg = 0$.
Since in general $a,c \neq 0$ I have to conclude that $d,g = 0$

This way of thinking seems to work. However when asked to find the orthogonal compliment of the subspace of symmetric matrices.

letting $U =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
b & c  \\
 \end{array} \right)$ 
and $V = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
d & e \\
f & g  \\
 \end{array} \right)$

then $tr (U^TV) = ad + be + bf + cg$

we would like

$ad + b(e + f) + cg = 0$

I think I am going about all this the wrong way.

Comment: Following your reasoning shouldn't $V$ be $V=\left(\matrix{0 & e\\-e & 0}\right)$?

Comment: Which $V$ are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $ad + b(e+f) + cg = 0$ and in general $a,b,c \neq 0 $ we need $d,(e+f),g = 0$ so like CTNT said above, by your reasoning

$$V =\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & e \\
-e & 0 \\
 \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: I see, If i take the trace of the matrix, it is always zero! THANKS.